# iOS : Is there any way to test .ipa file in multiple device without jailbreak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created .ipa file using ad-hoc as the app is in testing phase. I want to send this .ipa file to my friend in other country to test the app, but due to company policies, he cannot jailbreak the device. How to make .ipa file which can be executed in any iOS device?

Generated .ipa file from Xcode 4.6

Comment: You'll need an enterprise developer account for that. Otherwise you're limited to 100 specific devices for provisioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just register your friend's device to the Member Center and add it to your Ad-Hoc distribution certificate? Then re-distribute it.

Here is all the information you need : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Answer (score 5):

Get his device's UDID and add it to your list of devices in the profisioning portal. Then include the device in the certificate, download the updated certificate and 1) import it in xcode and re-build and 2) add it to the mail with the ipa file. He is supposed to copy the certificate into the apps folder in itunes and then cops the ipa there and sync the device.

If you happen to have more betatesters on distributed locations then you should look for services like testflightapp. https://testflightapp.com/ which provides convenient aid for you and the testers.

Comment: to import the certificate in xcode and re-build, i must have the device whose UDID number should match with the device for "buid and archive". The device must be connected rite? How can I build and archive for my device whose UDID number will be different from the person whom i am going to send the ipa file

Comment: No, you just need the number. The owner of the device can sent it to you. He sees it in itunes. (He connects the device to iTunes and clicks on the serial number, it may not be possible to copy it from there though. That makes it error prone) Alternatively he can download one of the vast number of free UUID apps that read the ID and emails it to you. You can maintain up to 100 devices in the provistioning portal.

Comment: Hermann, how to copy the certificate into the apps folder? Drag dropping ios_distribution.cer in apps section of iTunes does not work.

Comment: @DeepakThakur, it does work. At leat it should. The issue is that you don't get any feedback from iTunes. No "OK" no nothing. The only way of checking whether it has been copied is that you drag and drop it a second time. Then you will be asked whether to overwrite the existing file.    Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Add all of the devices to your developer account and adhoc profile and then distribute. Or sign up for an enterprise account and then you can distribute the app internally to your company.

Comment: Taken from his explanation and reading between the lines I don't think that his situation really fits the enterprse account's terms and conditions. Technically it should work fine though.

Comment: You can't just "sign up for an enterprise" account.
You have to satisfy the requirements to have an enterprise account.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use TestFlight: http://testflightapp.com/dashboard/

You can upload your ipa and invite your friends to be testers.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible and very easy.
So, you say you already have an ad-hoc provisioning profile. But actually only with one (your own) device ID. So here is, how to add more device IDs - no jailbreak necessary!

1. Ask your friend to connect his device to iTunes, and eMail his Device UID (DUID) to you (40 characters string)
2. Go to Apples Developer Member Center (iOS) web site, login with your account and head over to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".
3. Click on "Devices" and add your friends device (name and UDID).
4. Now click on "Provisioning Profiles" and select the existing ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile for your app and click "Edit" to add the new device of your friend
5. Now make Xcode refresh its internal provisioning profile database via menu "Window / Organizer" then click "Devices" tab and "Provisioning Profiles" on the top left. Then click menu "Editor / Refresh from Developer Portal"
6. Rebuild your app with your just updated provisioning profile (this should update the code signing of your app.
7. Via "Product Archive" generate your *.IPA
8. You should now EMail the *.ipa to your tester friend.

If you are fast with the above steps 2 to 8, your frind still has connected his device to iTunes (see step 1 above).
;-)
He now simply drag'n'drops the *.ipa file from your mail to iTunes and iTunes syncs the App to his device. The app should work. (Eventually the device installs the profile - but nothing can go wrong here).

DONE.

If you have multiple testers and mutiple builds, then have a look at http://www.testflightapp.com - this free of charge website makes distrubution of iOS apps for ad hoc testing even more easy. But it only saves time if you have multiple testers and multiple to be tested apps (or versions of one app).

Have fun!

Comment: He replied that the 'appname' failed to sync. I again followed each and every point of yours and sent him again and he still gets the same message.

Comment: Maybe your friend can send a screenshot? And you may attach it to your question.

Answer (score -2):

If you are developing on mac, Consider downloading multiple iOS and config your iphone simulator for those.